# simplying the following, $\frac{1}{x^2(1-\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{12}x^2)^2}...$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am running into a problem simplying the following,

$$\frac{1}{x^2(1-\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{12}x^2...)^2}$$

apparently it simplifies to,

$$\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{11}{12}+\frac{3}{4}x...$$

I'm wondering if someone could show me the steps that were skipped in-between, thanks!

Comment: yes I am actually

Comment: @B.Mehta could you help me now?

Comment: yes I will edit them in

Comment: Finally, you've tagged this both calculus and precalculus - which tools do you have? For instance, do you know the binomial theorem or Taylor's theorem?

Comment: could you show me one of those?

Comment: @B.Mehta I have covered both of calc and pre calc

Answer (score 1):

Use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-y)^2} =1+2y+3y^2+4y^3 +\cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}
with $y=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{(1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{12})^2} =\frac{1}{x^2} \left( 1+2(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12})+3(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12})^2+4(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12})^3 +\cdots \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now expand the brackets and you will obtain your result.